# Is it possible to get data both hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto, hortonworks-data-platform, hive-metastore

I have two **hadoop cluster** and i am moving one big table to another cluster.

But i do not have **enough space** to move the whole table and open the table to the users. So while i m moving the table to the another cluster i need to show my table data from both *hadoop cluster.*

I know i can use `presto` for this but the table is too big and i have problem with `presto` cluster server ram capacity.

So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using [Hadoop Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html)?

Comment: Yes we are using